# USB Boot not Working?

Tags: uefi, gparted, bios

I need to partition my HDD and I'm using GParted-Live to unmount it. The problem is that my BIOS won't load from USB (even though I set the boot priority to do USB before HDD). I think the USB is UEFI, even though I'm not sure what that means.

I have no idea what's the problem. The USB is showing up on Disks but not on Files, if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: You problem is not related to Ubuntu but with your way of booting; uefi demands you to pick the boot FROM the bios and not to change the bootorder. You need to actually tell the bios to boot from *your device*. There is an option in your BIOS that says "boot from generic device (EFI)" or if the brand is known "boot from Kingston (EFI)"